# How to withdraw from contract exact amount of ether?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, balances

Suppose I have a contract:

```
contract mycontract {
    constructor() payable {}
    
    function withdraw(uint256 amount) public {  
        // either
        //payable(address(msg.sender)).transfer(amount);
        // or
        (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: amount}("");
        require(success, "Transfer failed.");
    }
}
```

When I call `withdraw(100000000000000)`, I got my ether balance increased by `99999999973576` or so wei instead of `100000000000000`. Is it because of transaction cost? How can I fix this function to receive exactly `100000000000000` wei? And if it's tx cost, why it applied differently to "normal" transaction (like wallet to wallet)? Why tx cost doesn't deduced from contract balance, not from tx amount? Where one can read about it?